Loading a texture in a-sky causes lag
I'm making an app to create virtual visit based on 360° images and the A-Frame library. My problem is that when I load a new texture into the a-sky element, there is a lag: the scene is stuck, not refreshing during a period. For an image of 16384x8192px (the biggest I need) the lag is of more than 400ms, I can clearly see it in the Firefox profiler as a "jank - event processing delay" caused by WebGL2RenderingContext.texSubImage2D. The lag is only occurring the first time I load each texture. It is not related to the network.
I tried to prefetch the next textures into another a-sky element, but I'm only delaying the problem: now I got the lag because of the next image loading... It is not possible for me to preload all the set of images, it could be of a hundreds of pictures and only a handful may be needed. I would love that the prefetching would be done in background in another thread, not using 100% of the processor and not blocking the event loop.
As mentioned into the A-frame documentation, I resized the textures to a power of two, but it doesn't seems to change anything. The only way to not feel a lag is to use textures not bigger than 2048*1024px which is clearly too low.
Firefox 125 / Debian, Kubuntu
Chromium 124 / Debian, Kubuntu
A-Frame Version: 1.5.0

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=715919
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1486454
